# How to press ENTER key from Robot class?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, awtrobot

I have created a method to click a specific addon from firefox toolbar and everything is working fine on Windows os. But when I try to perform the same action from Jenkins server that is using a Linux machine it can not perform the robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Enter).

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //move to addons
    Robot robot1 = new Robot();
    robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //move to simple-modify-header addon
    Robot robot3 = new Robot();
    robot3.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot3.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot3.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot3.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot3.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot3.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot3.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot3.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    Thread.sleep(2000);


    //click simple-modify-header addon
    Robot robot2 = new Robot();
    robot2.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot2.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

I tried using different robot instances, but it is still stucking on pressin ENTER.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
public static void robotDoEnter()
    {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.delay(300);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.delay(300);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to add a delay between keyPress() and keyRelease() lines but I am still having the same issue. I am not able to press ENTER key on linux. On windows everything is working fine.

Comment: Well, I used this on Windows only and it worked perfect. Did not try on Linux or Mac, sorry.

Comment: Do you have to use Robot? Actions will not be an option?

Comment: I tried it also with Actions but still the same problem. I added a screenshot on the post and with robot class I can go to simple-modify-headers and then when i want to click enter it is opening the pop-up.